# HOw run the android application on physical device

Tags: android, device-emulation

i made the connection between emulatore and physical device via USB.I had follow the link [link](http://javatech.org/2011/01/discovering-android-running-on-a-physical-device/)but also it is not working properly it is running on the virtual device only.

when i  am reseting adb then it is showing following error

```
[2012-04-04 10:06:40 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2012-04-04 10:06:41 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
[2012-04-04 11:00:41 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2012-04-04 11:00:42 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
[2012-04-04 11:32:53 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Comment: please specify properly what you want.

Comment: @KKD ... its pretty clear what he wants..

Comment: well ASR edited it just now...

Comment: i have not edited  requirement of the user i am editing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you working with Eclipse? You have to connect your mobile device (with usb debugging mode on) with eclipse. How to do that, you can read here: [Running APK on Device](http://javatech.org/2011/01/discovering-android-running-on-a-physical-device/)

edit: oh, it's the same link like yours, so what's the problem..?

Comment: i have follow all thing but it is running on virtual device only

Comment: you should try to manually copy the apk file to your device. Do this by the command line. By the way, have you installed all necessary drivers for your device?

Comment: how to do it manually.I don't know ?

Comment: like @harishn said, you can use `adb push .apk /system/app/.apk` to manually put the apk file on your device. For this, please read the basic instructions of the [android debug bridge](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html)

Comment: after the basic instructions, try to execute `adb -s yourdevice install yourfile.apk`. This should install the apk on your device (you see the portnumber/name in the configuration)

Answer (score 3):

There are two methods.

1. First enable USB debugging in your device and connect to development PC. Use **ADB** tool to install your .apk file in device you connected.
2. Connect your device to PC. After select Turn on USB storage by dragging the notifications area. After that you can see your device as one removable media in your PC. copy your .apk file to this drive. After disconnect your device and check the option **allow installation from unknown resources** from **Settings** in your device. Now  open file manger and open your .apk file recently copied. It will ask you to install this apk.

Comment: can you elaborate what is adb tool

Comment: ADB means Android debug bridge. Visit this link[ADB](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html)

Comment: my means how to install apk file from adbtool

Comment: i given link about ADB, it is good to check there. It seem to be you are not interested to search online. it is not good practice. Visit the link i given, there you can find everything we can do with adb tool.

Answer (score 2):

Enable USB debugging on your phone (Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB debugging). You should now be able to deploy the app, provided you have set up the development environment correctly (ADT and the SDK must be downloaded and configured accordingly).

Comment: i have done this also but it is not working ? i have edited my question you should check that..

Comment: @ASR .. you try installing proper pc suit too.. I  mean the device drivers..

Comment: what os version are you using on your device? perhaps it does not match the minimum requirements of the app.

Comment: i am galaxy y and my software requirement is 2.2

Comment: yeah you need to install the proper device drivers. and make sure the device is actually plugged in.

Comment: go to the manifest file of your app. check this line : <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />. make sure your device has a version number which is compatible with the minSdkVersion.

Answer (score 1):

From command line, Go to android platform tools where adb is located. For the application you have created a .apk file would be generated

Use the below command to push the apk to the device.

adb push .apk  /system/app/.apk

After pushing the apk, it would be ready to run on the device

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse then this may be the solution

right click on the project-> Run As-> Run Configuration ->  select Automatic -> uncheck all the device name in the list -> click on Apply-> Click On run

If both emulator and physical device is running it will prompt to select one.